# correctly access the role after logging in as a user in Angular 17

Tags: angular

I am trying to redirect my user according to his role, after logging in, he can log in perfectly, this is the response:

```
{"status":true,"message":"Login succeed","data":{"id":"1","email":"alexanderquiroz@info-mat.com","oauth_uid":null,"oauth_provider":null,"roles":"ROLE_ADMIN","username":"alexanderquiroz","full_name":"alexanderquiroz","avatar":"","banned":"0","last_login":"2024-02-23 13:04:02","last_activity":"2024-02-23 09:45:49","date_created":"2024-02-05 15:12:50","forgot_exp":null,"remember_time":"2024-02-08 00:00:00","remember_exp":"Ak4LE5igMv8zwoOh","verification_code":null,"top_secret":null,"ip_address":"186.7.228.195"},"token":"tokenJwt"}
```

I receive this response, in my aap.component and then redirect the user to their board, here my app.component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { StorageService } from './_services/storage.service';
import { AuthService } from './_services/auth.service';
import { EventBusService } from './_shared/event-bus.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private roles: string[] = ['ROLE_ADMIN'];

  isLoggedIn = false;
  showAdminBoard = false;
  showModeratorBoard = false;
  username?: string;

  eventBusSub?: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private storageService: StorageService,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private eventBusService: EventBusService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isLoggedIn = this.storageService.isLoggedIn();

    if (this.isLoggedIn) {
      const user = this.storageService.getUser();
      this.roles = user.roles;

      this.showAdminBoard = this.roles.includes('ROLE_ADMIN');
      this.showModeratorBoard = this.roles.includes('ROLE_MODERATOR');

      this.username = user.username;
    }

    this.eventBusSub = this.eventBusService.on('logout', () => {
      this.logout();
    });
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.authService.logout().subscribe({
      next: res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.storageService.clean();

        window.location.reload();
      },
      error: err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

also here my login.component of how I log in

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../_services/auth.service';
import { StorageService } from '../_services/storage.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  form: any = {
    username: null,
    password: null
  };
  isLoggedIn = false;
  isLoginFailed = false;
  errorMessage = '';
  roles: string[] = [];

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private storageService: StorageService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.storageService.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
      this.roles = this.storageService.getUser().roles;
    }
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    const { username, password } = this.form;

    this.authService.login(username, password).subscribe({
      next: data => {
        this.storageService.saveUser(data);

        this.isLoginFailed = false;
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        this.roles = this.storageService.getUser().roles;
        this.reloadPage();
      },
      error: err => {
        this.errorMessage = err.error.message;
        this.isLoginFailed = true;
      }
    });
  }

  reloadPage(): void {
    window.location.reload();
  }
}
```

Also how to save the information in my storage service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

const USER_KEY = 'auth-user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StorageService {
  constructor() {}

  clean(): void {
    window.sessionStorage.clear();
  }

  public saveUser(user: any): void {
    window.sessionStorage.removeItem(USER_KEY);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem(USER_KEY, JSON.stringify(user));
  }

  public getUser(): any {
    const user = window.sessionStorage.getItem(USER_KEY);
    if (user) {
      return JSON.parse(user);
    }

    return null;
  }

  public isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const user = window.sessionStorage.getItem(USER_KEY);
    if (user) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

According to what I have here, it is not working for me, I cannot get the user to be redirected to the role, which brings me the response in the json

Comment: Are you getting any error in browser? Also I don't see any code for redirect.

Comment: Hello, what it does is come back. to reload the page, identifying if it is logged in or not and showing another html, I will put the routes, what interests me is to be able to access in the response, the "roles" column but I can't capture the value, or I don't know if I do it correctly